# Transforming long list-like string into a new list

Tags: python, regex, scikit-learn

I have a question related to (pre-)processing text information. My data structure in each csv row is as follows:

```
row = "['Adventure' 'African elephant' 'Animal' 'Ball game' 'Bay' 'Body of water' 'Communication Device' 'Electronic device']"
```

**The desired outcome after transformation:**

```
[adventure, african_elephant, animal, ball_game, bay, body_of_water, communication_device, electronic_device]
```

**Question:** **How can I solve this best and most efficient (100,000 documents)?** RegEx and non-RegEx solutions in Python welcome.

**Solutions:**

```
%%time
import ast
row = "['Adventure' 'African elephant' 'Animal' 'Ball game' 'Bay' 'Body of water' 'Communication Device' 'Electronic device']"
row = ast.literal_eval(','.join(['_'.join(i.lower().split()) for i in row.split("' '")]))[0].split(',')
row

CPU times: user 43 µs, sys: 1 µs, total: 44 µs
Wall time: 48.2 µs

%%time
row = "['Adventure' 'African elephant' 'Animal' 'Ball game' 'Bay' 'Body of water' 'Communication Device' 'Electronic device']"
row = [w.lower().replace(' ', '_') for w in re.findall(r"'([^']*)'", row)]
row

CPU times: user 25 µs, sys: 1e+03 ns, total: 26 µs
Wall time: 29.1 µs
```

Comment: Other Python solutions are welcome, too. I'm working with gensim that offers a few [preprocessing options](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/parsing/preprocessing.html), but not for that case. I thought RegEx would be the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this code:

```
>>> row = "['Adventure' 'African elephant' 'Animal' 'Ball game' 'Bay' 'Body of water' 'Communication Device' 'Electronic device']"
>>> [w.replace(' ', '_') for w in re.findall(r"'([^']*)'", row.lower())]
['adventure', 'african_elephant', 'animal', 'ball_game', 'bay', 'body_of_water', 'communication_device', 'electronic_device']
```

**Details:**

- `row.lower()`: converts input string to lowercase
- `re.findall` converts lowercase input string into a list by finding substring enclosed by single quotes
- `w.replace` replaces space with `_` in each element of the list

Comment: It seems this solution is a bit faster, thank you! I updated the question with two solutions and a benchmark above.

Comment: Actually I updated my answer afterwards. Calling `lower()` upfront instead of on each item so this one might be even bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

Simple list comprehension

```
import ast
document = "['Adventure' 'African elephant' 'Animal' 'Ball game' 'Bay' 'Body of water' 'Communication Device' 'Electronic device']"
ast.literal_eval(','.join(['_'.join(i.lower().split()) for i in document.split("' '")]))
```

Output(as list which contains single string)

```
['adventure,african_elephant,animal,ball_game,bay,body_of_water,communication_device,electronic_device']
```

Now if you need list of strings

```
ast.literal_eval(','.join(['_'.join(i.lower().split()) for i in document.split("' '")]))[0].split(',')
```

Output

```
['adventure',
 'african_elephant',
 'animal',
 'ball_game',
 'bay',
 'body_of_water',
 'communication_device',
 'electronic_device']
```

Comment: This gives `['adventureafrican elephantanimalball gamebaybody of watercommunication deviceelectronic device']` (similar like below). I'm on Python 3, if that helps?

Comment: This is because your input is neither a valid string nor a list of words. I have treated them as a list of words

Comment: See below. Unfortunately, each row in a csv column looks like: `"['word1' 'word2' 'word3']"`

Comment: Again you have to pre-process in order to do something `'word1' 'word2' 'word3'` will be treated as a single string. if it is similar to `"['word1', 'word2' ,'word3']"` you can convert list embedded in string using `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: I'm checking that one. Note that I updated the example above. Indeed every row starts and ends with a ".

Comment: It seems the solution below is a bit faster, thank you! I updated the question with two solutions and a benchmark above.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
import re
document = "['Adventure' 'African elephant' 'Animal' 'Ball game' 'Bay' 'Body of water' 'Communication Device' 'Electronic device']"
list = re.findall("'([^']*)'", document)
```